# Route parameters in Express JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I am using Express JS to handle a route `http://localhost:3000/location` which allows a mix of parameters and fixed endpoints. For example:

`http://localhost:3000/location` is the root for the route, which renders a view for a list of locations.

`http://localhost:3000/location/map` renders a view for a list of the locations drawn on a web map.

`http://localhost:3000/location/:id` contains a parameter for the ID of a location given in the URL and when called, renders a view for the details of the given location that comes from a database query.

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET route root page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  // DO SOMETHING
});

/* GET the map page */
router.get('/map', function(req, res, next) {
  // DO SOMETHING
});

/* GET individual location. */
router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  // DO SOMETHING
});

module.exports = router;
```

Is this a best practise for handling a route with mixed fixed values and parameterized parameters?

More specifically, how to properly handle the problem that when I called "http://localhost:3000/location/SOMETHINGWRONG", for example, `http://localhost:3000/location/:id` was triggered which led to a database query error because "SOMETHINGWRONG" was not an integer and could not pass?

Answer (score 5):

You can restrict a rule with regex in your route, for example, if you only expect to receive whole numbers, you can use something like this:

```
router.get('/:id(\\d{12})', (req, res) => {
  //...
});
```

Enter the method if you meet the rule, where "id" is a number with 12 characters

Validate only numbers:

```
app.get('/:id(\\d+)', function (req, res){ 
  //...
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I changed the code as your answer. When I called "http://localhost:3000/location/579" for example, it gave me a 404 Not Found error.

Comment: Validate only numbers, use this example

`app.get('/:id(\\d+)', function (req, res){
  // req.params.id is now defined here for you
});`

Answer (score 3):

To have more control over the exact string that can be matched by a route parameter, you can append a regular expression in parentheses (()).
ex: Your Id is an integer with a maximum length of 10 characters

```
/* GET individual location. */
router.get('/:id([0-9]{1,10})', function(req, res, next) {
  // DO SOMETHING
});
```